Add extra vertices on LineString where they cross Polygon edges
I have two GeoPandas GeoDataFrames; one containing Polygons, and the other LineStrings:

Corresponding sample data:
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString

gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
  'geom': [
    Polygon(((32, 41), (34, 44), (36, 42), (32, 41))),
    Polygon(((34, 44), (36, 42), (37, 44), (34, 44))),
    Polygon(((36, 42), (37, 41), (37, 44), (36, 42))),
    Polygon(((37, 44), (39, 46), (40, 42), (37, 44))),
    Polygon(((37, 44), (40, 42), (37, 41), (37, 44))),
    Polygon(((37, 41), (36, 40), (36, 42), (37, 41))),
    Polygon(((36, 40), (32, 41), (36, 42), (36, 40))),
    Polygon(((37, 44), (36, 46), (34, 44), (37, 44))),
    Polygon(((36, 46), (39, 46), (37, 44), (36, 46))),
  ]}, geometry='geom', crs=2056
)

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
  'geom': [
    LineString(((33.0204, 39.937), (35.429, 40.534), (35.795, 41.170), (37.183, 41.691), (37.954, 42.365), (38.262, 43.849), (40.112, 45.661))),
    LineString(((38.2624, 43.849), (37.183, 43.406), (36.258, 43.406), (35.352, 43.772), (34.118, 43.387), (33.116, 42.288), (31.575, 41.806))),
    LineString(((35.3523, 43.772), (37.048, 45.198), (38.802, 46.316))),
    LineString(((32.2302, 40.554), (33.868, 41.113), (34.408, 42.365), (35.352, 43.772)))
  ]}, geometry='geom', crs=2056
)

I want to find the fastest and most memory-efficient way to add extra vertices to all lines where they cross the polygons' edges, i.e. adding the green points in the following figure as new vertices to each existing line:

I've tried to use the overlay() method:
gdf3 = gdf1.overlay(gdf2, how='intersection', keep_geom_type=False)

it seems to work well at first glance, but... lines are split into many (here 15) small parts as if the polygons were cookie cutters. Whereas I'd like the original lines to have these extra vertices but remain as they are, i.e. 4 complete entities.
What I'm looking after is something such as the segmentize() method but instead of using a maximum segment length, I wish it could use the intersection with the underlying polygons' edges.

GeoPandas: 1.0.1
Shapely: 2.0.3


I think applying the difference of the boundary lines of the polygons on the linestrings will give you what you are looking for:

Something like this:
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import BASE_COLORS
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString
from shapely.plotting import plot_line


gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
  'geom': [
    Polygon(((32, 41), (34, 44), (36, 42), (32, 41))),
    Polygon(((34, 44), (36, 42), (37, 44), (34, 44))),
    Polygon(((36, 42), (37, 41), (37, 44), (36, 42))),
    Polygon(((37, 44), (39, 46), (40, 42), (37, 44))),
    Polygon(((37, 44), (40, 42), (37, 41), (37, 44))),
    Polygon(((37, 41), (36, 40), (36, 42), (37, 41))),
    Polygon(((36, 40), (32, 41), (36, 42), (36, 40))),
    Polygon(((37, 44), (36, 46), (34, 44), (37, 44))),
    Polygon(((36, 46), (39, 46), (37, 44), (36, 46))),
  ]}, geometry='geom', crs=2056
)

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
  'geom': [
    LineString(((33.0204, 39.937), (35.429, 40.534), (35.795, 41.170), (37.183, 41.691), (37.954, 42.365), (38.262, 43.849), (40.112, 45.661))),
    LineString(((38.2624, 43.849), (37.183, 43.406), (36.258, 43.406), (35.352, 43.772), (34.118, 43.387), (33.116, 42.288), (31.575, 41.806))),
    LineString(((35.3523, 43.772), (37.048, 45.198), (38.802, 46.316))),
    LineString(((32.2302, 40.554), (33.868, 41.113), (34.408, 42.365), (35.352, 43.772)))
  ]}, geometry='geom', crs=2056
)
print(f"{len(gdf2)=}, with respectively {list(shapely.get_num_coordinates(gdf2.geometry))} coordinates")

# Split the lines in gdf2 by the boundaries of gdf1
gdf1_boundaries = gdf1.set_geometry(gdf1.boundary)
gdf3 = gdf2.overlay(gdf1_boundaries, how='difference')
print(f"{len(gdf3)=}, with respectively {list(shapely.get_num_coordinates(gdf3.geometry))} coordinates")
print(f"{gdf3=}")

# Merge the split lines from multilinestrings to linestrings
gdf4 = gdf3.set_geometry(gdf3.line_merge())
print(f"{len(gdf4)=}, with respectively {list(shapely.get_num_coordinates(gdf4.geometry))} coordinates")
print(f"{gdf4=}")

for i in range(len(gdf4)):
  plot_line(gdf4.geometry[i], color=list(BASE_COLORS)[i])
plt.show()

Output:
len(gdf2)=4, with respectively [7, 7, 3, 4] coordinates
len(gdf3)=4, with respectively [19, 17, 9, 10] coordinates
gdf3=                                                geom
0  MULTILINESTRING ((33.02 39.937, 34.643 40.339)...
1  MULTILINESTRING ((38.262 43.849, 37.621 43.586...
2  MULTILINESTRING ((35.352 43.772, 35.623 44), (...
3  MULTILINESTRING ((32.23 40.554, 32.887 40.778)...
len(gdf4)=4, with respectively [13, 12, 6, 7] coordinates
gdf4=                                                geom
0  LINESTRING (33.02 39.937, 34.643 40.339, 35.42...
1  LINESTRING (38.262 43.849, 37.621 43.586, 37.1...
2  LINESTRING (35.352 43.772, 35.623 44, 36.593 4...
3  LINESTRING (32.23 40.554, 32.887 40.778, 33.86...


Thank your for your answer! It's really nice because it keeps the entities as they are, but I cannot understand why it completely decomposes the LineString into MultiLineString (where each part is always a single segment of the whole line).

I suppose that because conceptually the boundaries are being "cut away", the lines are also being cut in seperate linestrings... hence they are multilinestrings. They can easily be merged again to single linestrings... I added that to the script as well.
